# Can't see cookie in headers returned from server in Angular 6 application but can see it in Postman

Tags: cookies, angular6

I am running an Angular 6 application. Im sending a POST request to an API, and they return me a 200 OK and they also set a cookie. When I make the request in Postman, i can see the cookie set in the response headers however my Angular app does not set the cookie?

```
login(loginDetails: any): Observable<any> {
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

return this.http
  .post(this.getRootUrl() + '/Login',  JSON.stringify(loginDetails), {headers: headers, withCredentials: true, observe: 'response'})
  .map((response: any) => {
    // console.log(response);
    return true;
  })
```

}

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: In common case , we set cookie in browser not in res or in header.

Comment: As per your code , You call login API, which gives you res, and you want to store that in cookie ? Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **set cookie** after call API of login.

```
login(data).subscribe((response: any) => {
if (response.code == 200) {
    this.commonService.setCookie('userAuthData', response.data);                
    // Redirect to dashboard page 
  }
  else {        
    // Redirect to login page 
  }
});
```

In common service :

```
import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";

constructor(private cookieService: CookieService)...
setCookie(key, value) {
   this.cookieService.set(key, value, 1, '/');
}
```